# How to find and replace UILabel's value on a specific line?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I know I can find the total number of lines of a `UILabel` with `.numberOfLines` but how can I retrieve and edit the value say on line 2.

Example:
[image: Get/edit this value]

Comment: querying your user interface for data is a terrible approach. If you need that info keep it when you generate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your screen shot that each line is separated by a newline character you can split the text based on that.

Here is an example in Swift 3:

```
if let components = label.text?.components(separatedBy: "\n"), components.count > 1 {
    let secondLine = components[2]
    let editedSecondLine = secondLine + "edited"
    label.text = label.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: secondLine, with: editedSecondLine)
}
```

You should make sure there is a value at whatever index your interested in. This example makes sure that there are more than a single component before retrieving the value.

You can then replace the second line with your edited line.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This code assumes the line wrapping only happens on newlines. That may or may not be a valid assumption.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming so for this example based on their screenshot.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the case here, brilliant